# Open hidden view

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have a perspective with two views, at the beginning of the application shows a viewA and hides the viewB. It´s possible the user select an item from the table in viewA and that selection open viewB which at the beginning is hidden, while hiding viewA?

Answer (score 1):

supouse you have a TableViewer, on your View, you do this:

```
this.yourTableViewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {
        public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
            IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();
            if (selection .isEmpty()) {
                MessageHelper.openWarning("Select something");
                return;
            }

            try {
               //opens a Editor instead a view
                getSite().getPage().openEditor(new UsuarioEditorInput((Usuario) selecao.getFirstElement()), "br.com.germantech.ecf.usuarioEditor");
            }
            catch (PartInitException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);

Comment: Sorry, the previous message was a mistake. Also sent to  viewB the selected item by clicking vistaB and use "getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);" . Does the viewer have a listener and send the item?

Comment: Sorry again, I wanted to write "Also sent to viewB the selected item by clicking viewA(only one click)"

Comment: I open an editor so I can track changes in my model with the method `isDirty`

Comment: A view can have also a dirty state. All you have to do is to let the `org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart` implement `org.eclipse.ui.ISaveablePart`